# Como adicionar 2 dias a uma data e colocar o valor no HTML

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho a seguinte tag em HTML:

```html
<h1 id="newDate" style="align: center; font-weight: 100; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 24px; color: rgb(28, 7, 7);"></h1>
```

Preciso de um código JavaScript para adicionar dia e mês e acrescentar dois dias à data. Mas o JavaScript tem de ser inserido em folha à parte e chamar este `h1` pelo `id` para inserir nele a data. Como faço isso?

Comment: 1) Pesquise como carregar um arquivo JS no HTML; 2) Pesquise como selecionar o elemento da DOM a partir do id. A parte de adicionar datas você já deve ter visto nas perguntas duplicadas da sua outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para somar dois dias a uma data, basta usar um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) e somar 2 ao valor de [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) (usando [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) para atualizar o valor):

```js
let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); // somar 2 dias
```

Detalhe: se o dia for, por exemplo, 30 de abril, ao somar 2 o valor passa a ser 32. Mas **felizmente** o método `setDate()` já faz os ajustes automaticamente, resultando em 2 de maio. O mesmo vale para outras datas, como 31 de dezembro (ao somar 2, o valor do dia passa a ser 33, mas é ajustado para 1 de janeiro do ano seguinte) e 28 ou 29 de fevereiro em anos bissextos (você não precisa se preocupar se o ano é bissexto ou não, `setDate()` já faz os ajustes corretamente).

<sup><sub>*Este é um erro que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/373229/112052) está cometendo: ela soma o valor do dia manualmente, sem se atentar para esses casos especiais, em que é preciso ajustar os valores. "Funciona" para muitos casos, mas falha para vários outros.*</sub></sup>

No exemplo acima eu uso a data atual, mas o código para somar 2 dias é o mesmo para qualquer data que você tenha (e como não ficou claro de onde vem esta data, vou deixar o exemplo assim mesmo).

Agora vem a parte de adicionar esta data no `h1` (retirei os *styles* para focar na parte que interessa):

```html
<h1 id="newDate"></h1>
```

Este elemento tem um [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), então podemos obtê-lo usando [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Em seguida, pode setar o [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) do mesmo para colocar a data dentro dele:

```js
let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); // somar 2 dias
// buscar elemento cujo id é newDate, e colocar a data como seu conteúdo
document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<h1 id="newDate"></h1>
```

Com isso, o texto dentro do `h1` será algo do tipo:

> Sat Apr 06 2019 11:05:43 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)

**Na verdade, a saída exata vai variar**, não só por causa da data/hora atual, mas também por causa do fuso horário que estiver configurado no seu browser (que por *default* é o do sistema operacional).

De qualquer forma, o formato acima é o mesmo retornado por [`d.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) (que é o *default* usado quando atribuímos o `Date` diretamente para `innerHTML`). Se quiser a data em outro formato, terá que fazer isso manualmente. Por exemplo, para formatá-la como `dd/mm/aaaa`:

```js
let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); // somar 2 dias
let dataFormatada = `${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML = dataFormatada;
```

```html
<h1 id="newDate"></h1>
```

Agora o resultado é `06/04/2019` (se rodar o código hoje, obviamente - estou usando a data atual, então amanhã o resultado será `07/04/2019`).
Um detalhe chato é que `getMonth()` retorna o valor do mês indexado em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), então sempre precisa lembrar de somar 1.

Também usei a sintaxe de [*template string*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), delimitada por `` ` `` e que possibilita colocar expressões dentro dela (delimitadas por `${}`). Mas se quiser, também pode usar a boa e velha sintaxe de concatenação de strings:

```js
let dataFormatada = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + '/'
                    + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '/'
                    + d.getFullYear();
```

Outra opção é usar [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), que retorna a data no formato específico do *locale* (do idioma padrão) que está configurado no browser. No meu caso o browser está em português do Brasil, então o retorno é `06/04/2019`. Se o browser estiver em inglês americano, o retorno será `4/6/2019`.

Você também pode passar um código de locale específico, para não depender das configurações do browser. Por exemplo, para português do Brasil, use `d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')`, e assim será usado o formato referente ao português do Brasil, independente do que estiver configurado no browser (lembrando que os formatos que dependem de um *locale* podem variar, conforme explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408649/112052)).

---

Outro detalhe é que mudando o valor do `innerHTML` você altera todo o conteúdo do `h1`. Por exemplo, se ele já tiver um texto antes, este será sobrescrito:

```js
let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); // somar 2 dias
let dataFormatada = `${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML = dataFormatada;
```

```html
<h1 id="newDate">Um texto qualquer</h1>
```

Repare que `Um texto qualquer` some e é substituído pela data. Mas também é possível acrescentar a data ao texto já existente, concatenando-a ao `innerHTML`:

```js
let d = new Date(); // data atual
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2); // somar 2 dias
let dataFormatada = `${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML += ' ' + dataFormatada;
//                                           ^^ concatenar em vez de sobrescrever
```

```html
<h1 id="newDate">Um texto qualquer</h1>
```

Agora o texto do `h1` é `Um texto qualquer 06/04/2019`.

---

### Moment.js

Outra alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), uma excelente biblioteca para lidar com datas. Talvez pareça exagero adicionar uma biblioteca só para isso, mas se [tem gente que adiciona dependências para coisas bem mais triviais](https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/), porque não usar uma para algo mais complexo, como lidar com datas? (e acredite, aritmética de datas [é mais difícil do que parece](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/)):

```js
let d = moment(); // data atual
// ou, se você já tiver um Date, faça:  d = moment(date)
d.add(2, 'days'); // somar 2 dias
document.getElementById('newDate').innerHTML = d.format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // formatar a data
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="newDate"></h1>
```

---

Se em vez da data atual, quiser criar uma data específica, basta fazer:

```js
// criando data de 3 de abril de 2019

// com Date
let d = new Date(2019, 3, 3);

// com Moment.js
let d = moment([2019, 3, 3]);
```

Ambos os exemplos acima criam a data de **3 de abril de 2019**. O detalhe é que, como já foi dito, os meses são indexados em zero, por isso abril é o mês 3.

Em seguida, para somar 1 dia a esta data, basta usar os métodos já citados acima.

---

Nos exemplos acima eu também poderia usar [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) em vez de `innerHTML`. Para os casos específicos desta pergunta, o resultado é o mesmo, mas é interessante saber que [há casos em que pode fazer diferença usar um ou outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/329975/112052).

---

Para colocar o JavaScript na sua página, basta usar a tag `script`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="arquivo.js"></script>
```

Sobre este ponto específico, sugiro [esta leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1109/112052).

Answer (score -1):

```
function datacorrig(){
    dayName = new Array ("00","01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12","13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24","25", "26", "27", "28","29", "30", "31"); 
    monName = new Array ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
    var d = new Date();
    var tp = d.getFullYear()+"-"+monName[d.getMonth()]+"-"+dayName[d.getDate()+2];
    document.getElementById("newDate").innerHTML = tp;
}
```

Comment: Se `d.getDate()` for dia 30 ou 31, o código falha, pois vai tentar acessar posições que não existem no array `dayName`. Além disso, tem vários outros casos para se atentar: se a data for no fim do mês, o resultado deve ser no mês seguinte (então não adianta pegar sempre o mesmo mês), e se for no fim de dezembro, o ano também deve mudar. Aritmética de datas é mais complicada do que parece, mas de qualquer forma vc complicou à toa, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/349847/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176793/112052) para ver como fazer isso em JavaScript...

Comment: Lhe dei apenas uma reta meu amigo você aeh já cria suas proprias verificações batata